# How to have a DIV with fixed aspect ratio and max-height? (Pure CSS/no vh or vw)

Tags: css, firefox, aspect-ratio, intrinsic-content-size

My initial problem like many others is to keep a DIV A with a fixed aspect ratio (pure CSS/no JS). It is intended to be reused in any parent DIV B regardless the sizing of B. DIV A should fit the smallest size of B.

[image: DIV with fixed aspect ratio]

In this animation, you can see the RED div that is always a square and that fits the outermost div smallest size.

No vh or vw or vmin or vmax is used and I don't want to use any of them because vh is sometimes no more reliable to really represent the viewport height (see [CSS3 100vh not constant in mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112218/css3-100vh-not-constant-in-mobile-browser) )

To do this, I used an image (grey rectangle) with a fixed aspect ratio (1/1 here), that expands to fit its parent.
It works as follows:

1) #container (thin dashed pink border) is the outermost DIV. It could be the full viewport or any DIV with a given size. Dimensions = H x contW

2) #widthwrapper (blue border) height is H (height: 100%). It wraps the img.

3) #imgwrapper is the image (big grey rectangle). Its height is also H (height: 100%). Since it is a square, its width = H.

4) #widthwrapper wraps the img and its basic width is: fit-content = img width = H. Since its max-width = 100% you have #widthwrapper width = min(H, contW). So #widthwrapper is such as w x h = min(H, contW) x H. #widthwrapper si also position: relative.

5) #content is position: absolute next to #widthwrapper and occupies the same space that #widthwrapper. So #content is such as w x h = min(H, contW) x H.

6) #contentwrapper (dashed red) is vertically centered in #content. With the padding-bottom hack it is a square with width = 100%. So dimensions of #contentwrapper are w x h = min(H, contW) x min(H, contW).

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#container {top: 5px;left: 5px;right: 5px;bottom: 5px;position: fixed;border: 1px dashed pink;}
*, *:before, *:after {box-sizing: content-box;}
#widthwrapper {height: 100%;min-height:100%;max-height:100%;max-width: 100%;margin: auto;width: -moz-fit-content; width: -webkit-fit-content; width: fit-content;position: relative;outline: 1px solid blue;border: 1px dashed blue;}
#imgwrapper {height: 100%;min-height: 100%;max-height: 100%;}
#content {position: absolute;top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0;display: flex;flex-direction: column;justify-content: center;align-items: center;}
#contentwrapper {height: 0;width: 100%;padding-bottom: 100%;outline: 3px dashed red;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="widthwrapper">
        <img id="imgwrapper" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 10 10'%3E%3Crect x='0' y='0' width='10' height='10' fill='none' stroke='black' stroke-opacity='0.3' /%3E%3C/svg%3E" />
        <div id="content">
            <div id="contentwrapper">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

BUT if on one side it works with Chrome/Safari, it is buggy with Firefox. Indeed, Firefox seems unable to include the image in #widthwrapper once resized. It resizes the image but #widthwrapper stays as if the image were w x h = 0 x 0. More generally, Firefox seems not to propagate to parent DIV an img width with no intrinsic size that is resized on an aspect ratio and height basis...

[image: problem with Firefox to wrap a resized image with no intrinsic size]

Any ideas to have this working with Firefox is welcome...(I have filled a bug at Bugzilla...if you fell to support it :-) ... https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1491936 )

Comment: Are you bug hunting or really trying to get a working layout?

Comment: I want this to work on all browser because I need it for my website...

Comment: Is div B always the size of viewport, div A always square?

Comment: No, in this example A is #container and B is #contentwrapper. But there are intermediate DIV between A and B. The goal is to have B/#contentwrapper always square inside A but never exceeding A height or width.

Comment: Isn't the inner div always square?

Comment: No the only square DIV is #contentwrapper

Comment: That is difficult to understand but good luck see anyone can pick up if possible. You might want to simplify the demo a bit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180250/discussion-between-beuun-and-stickers).

Comment: I have edited and rephrased the problem to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Did you ever find a good cross-browser solution for this?